# .replaceDataSource() results in ValueError: Layer: Unexpected error

Tags: arcpy, layers

I am replacing data sources for any of my layer files (.lyrs) that have a data source in L: . My code (in the Step 1 section) looks through each object in the ListLayers list first, determining which objects are actually layers (rather than group layers or service layers), then calls the fixLayer function for those layers. (I've posted these snippets in two separate chunks below to make it easier to follow).

In the end, I'm getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 67, in <module>
  File "<module1>", line 38, in fixLayer
  File "E:\sw_nt\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "E:\sw_nt\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\_mapping.py", line 681, in replaceDataSource
return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.replaceDataSource(*gp_fixargs((workspace_path, workspace_type, dataset_name, validate), True)))
ValueError: Layer: Unexpected error
```

The traceback to Line 67 is where I call the function; I'm calling it on the right hand side of the assignment statement in order to return the shpCount, FCCount and cvgCount variables to the global level. **Is this a problem?**

Here is the fixLayer function:

```
def fixLayer(x2):
    shpCount,FCCount,cvgCount = 0,0,0
if (x2.supports("DATASOURCE") and x2.dataSource[0:2] == "L:"): # improve this by subbing in a variable for L: so user can choose what x sources they want to update..
    layerString = x2.workspacePath
    layerName = str(x2.datasetName)
    print '\t',"Layer name is %s and full data source is %s" %(layerName, layerString)
    if x2.dataSource[-4:] == ".shp":    #detect workspace type for any layer source we could find in L:, be it shapefile, feature class or coverage
    #more slick: if extension.lower() == ".shp":
        workspaceType = "SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE"
        shpCount += 1
    elif '.gdb' in layerString:
        workspaceType = "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE"
        FCCount += 1
    else:
        workspaceType = "COVERAGE_WORKSPACE"
        cvgCount += 1
    print '\t', "%s has workspace type:  %s " %(layerString,workspaceType)
    newLayerString = str(layerString.replace(r"L:",r"W:\FOR\RSI\DKL\Local_Data",1))
    print "Checking arguments for .replaceDataSource:"
    print "Arguments are:\n 1. Workspace path: %s of type %s\n 2. Workspace type: %s of type %s and \n 3. Dataset name: %s of type %s" %(newLayerString,type(newLayerString),workspaceType,type(workspaceType), layerName, type(layerName))
    #Syntax for below:                 .replaceDataSource(workspace_path, workspace_type, dataset_name, {validate})
    lyr.replaceDataSource(newLayerString,workspaceType,layerName)
    #layerFile.replaceDataSource does not work because layerFile is a string; lyr is an object, which is required for the .replaceDataSource method
    lyr.save() #you've made changes to the object, now those changes need to be saved to the file
    print '\t',"The updated source for %s is %s." %(x2.name,lyr.dataSource)
else:
       print '\t', "Layer source does not need update."
return shpCount,FCCount,cvgCount
```

Here is my "Step 1" code block:

```
# Step 1: re-map layers in .lyr files in the main path
for layerFile in glob.glob(folder + "/*.lyr"):  #layerFile is a string
    lyrCount += 1
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layerFile)  # returns the object from each layer file
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(lyr) # returns the list of objects (i.e. the layer name, group layers (if any) and actual layers) referenced by the layer file
    print""
    print "Layer file is %s." %(layerFile)
    objectCount = 0
    grpLayerCount = 0
    for x in layers:
        objectCount +=1
        if x.isGroupLayer:
            grpLayerCount += 1
            print "%d. **GROUP LAYER** Object is %s." %( objectCount,str(x))
        elif x.isServiceLayer == 1:
            srvcCount += 1
            print"%s is a WMS layer" %(x.name)
        else:
            print "%d. Object is %s" %( objectCount,str(x))
            layerCount +=1
            a,b,c = fixLayer(x) #a,b,c correspond to the returned variables in fixLayer:  shpCount,FCCount,cvgCount
    shpCount += a
    FCCount += b
    cvgCount += c

   print""
   print"%s has %d objects including %d group layer(s)." %(layerFile,  len(layers),grpLayerCount)
   print "=========================================================================================="
```

Comment: What is line 38?

Comment: It is where I have .replaceDataSource in the def fixLayer block:

      lyr.replaceDataSource(newLayerString,workspaceType,layerName)

Comment: Are you changing the types of data, or just the path?

Comment: Just the path. The data types will be the same, just moved to a different folder.

Comment: If the filename is the same, just in a different path, try removing `layerName` from the tool - `lyr.replaceDataSource(newLayerString, workspaceType)`

Comment: Alternatively, try using `lyr.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath (find_workspace_path, replace_workspace_path, {validate})` to replace one path with another

Comment: (you will need to substitute your own values in that for the paths)

Comment: I have tried all this, still no luck. I also realized I need to have another parameter passed into my function , so the function definition is now:

`code`def fixLayer(x2,lyr2):




so the function call is now:
`code`a,b,c = fixLayer(x,lyr)

and I'm still suspicious of it; this line is the first line in the traceback, so I think that indicates the problem starts in the function call.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to incorporate any changes and response to comments

Comment: I also have no idea how to use this mini-Markdown formatting; 

I would think this
`code`
causes this line to be code

Comment: You put the ` on either side of your actual code

Comment: But if you [edit] your question you can just select the code and hit the `{}` button on the toolbar

Comment: Thanks! OK, so please comment on this (Line 70 now), which is the first line in the traceback:

`a,b,c = fixLayer(x,lyr)` 

Is that line a problem?

Comment: The error on that line is just referring to where the function is called that is raising the error. It's the second error line number that is the problem

Comment: Please reduce the code that you present to a single code snippet that can be used to illustrate your issue.

Comment: Try to omit `layerName` in `lyr.replaceDataSource(newLayerString,workspaceType,layerName)`. If you want to change the layer's name, use `lyr.name=layerName`. Also see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129741/valueerror-layer-unexpected-error-from-replacedatasource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here it is. If you're getting the following error:

**ValueError: Layer: Unexpected error**

when doing .replaceDataSource (a Layer method), it means A or B:

**A. that one of the arguments is wrong, either in terms of being the wrong data type or the wrong string i.e. a path that doesn’t exist**

Arguments for .replaceDataSource() are (examples):
 1. Workspace path: W:\FOR\RSI\DKL\Local_Data\ForestHealth\2009\Data of type 
 2. Workspace type: SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE of type  and 
 3. Dataset name: IBM_Treatments_May10_2010 of type

**B. It could also be that .replaceDataSource is working on the wrong object.** This is particularly the case for using .replaceDataSource on a layerfile object, rather than using .replaceDataSource on a layer within the list of layer returned by arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(layerfile object)